# Adding a <br> between Add to cart button with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add a "break" between my woocommerce add to cart button & quantity box(See photo 1)
[image: photo1]

This is the html(See photo)
[image: photo2]

I have tried this code

```
.quantity::after{
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre; 
}
```

Comment: first at all, images of code are unacceptable. Use copy & paste to copy the code here instead of letting us type it down from a picture. Laziness is not rewarded. Then, you cant add a `<br>` through pseudo-selectros like `::after`. Besides it is not needed as you have `margin-bottom `for that and stuff like `display: block / flex`.

Answer (score 1):

use **display: block;**

```
its Displays an element as a block element (like <p>). It starts on a new line, and takes up the whole width
```